# null object reference error using face detection on android camera

Tags: android, camera

I keep getting this error - "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"

I have made a camera that saves an image. I am now trying to detect faces in that image, but i keep getting this error when i run the code.. any help? I believe its because i am not passing the context to the facedetection class but i have tried many attempts with no success.. thanks

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Camera();

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Mat jpegData = new Mat(1, data.length, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                jpegData.put(0, 0, data);

                Mat bgrMat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(jpegData, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
                Core.transpose(bgrMat, bgrMat);
                Core.flip(bgrMat, bgrMat, 0);
                Imgproc.resize(bgrMat, bgrMat, bgrMat.size());

                File storagePath = new File(Environment.
                        getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Emotion Detection/");
                storagePath.mkdirs();
                File myImage = new File(storagePath,
                        Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                String imageString = myImage.toString();
                Mat newMat = new FaceDetection().run(bgrMat);
                Imgcodecs.imwrite(imageString, newMat);

                camera.startPreview();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Picture Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    }
```

Then in my facedetection class:

```
class FaceDetection extends Activity {

    private static final String    TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";
    private CascadeClassifier      mJavaDetector;
    private File                   mCascadeFile;

    public Mat run(Mat image) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning Face Detection");
        // Create a face detector from the cascade file in the resources
        // directory.
        // load cascade file from application resources
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
        File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        try {
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        if (mJavaDetector.empty())
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
            mJavaDetector = null;
        }
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

        cascadeDir.delete();


        // Detect faces in the image.
        // MatOfRect is a special container class for Rect.
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));
        // Draw a bounding box around each face.
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like FaceDetection class doesn't need to be an Activity if it only has the `run()` method and does nothing else.
According to Google's documentation:

> An Activity is an application component that provides a screen with which users can interact in order to do something, such as dial the phone, take a photo, send an email, or view a map.

Since your activity does not provide a screen that interacts with the user, remove the `extends Activity` from the FaceDetection class and take it out of the Activities package (put it in an utils folder, maybe? depends on your scope/architecture).

Finally, to call methods such as `getDir()` from outside an Activity, you will need a `Context`.

Add a `context` parameter to your method, like `public Mat run(Mat image, Context context)` and access `getDir()` through your context: `context.getDir()`.

The context you will pass to to the method can be the Activity on which the method is called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean by "take it out of the activities package"?? Also, my 'mCascadeFile' is now saying "cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @user3209940 The Activities directory. If you have a folder (package) for your activities, take it out from there. Create a folder named "utils" or "detections" or something else and put it there. It's just so your project structure looks organized.
As for the static error, I think it might be better to remove the "static" from the method. Just make a regular method without static and instantiate the "FaceDetection" class like: `FaceDetection faceDetection = new FaceDetection();`
`Mat newMat = faceDetection.run(bgrMat, MainActivity.this);`
I will update my answer. Tell me the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you instanciate an `Activity` with `new` it doesn't contain the necessary data. You need to start the Activity instead with `Context.startActivity`.

Alternatively, you can pass a `Context` to `run` and use it to get the `Resources`. But then it would be useless to implement this in an activity.

Answer (score 1):

check if the size of res/Raw/lbpcascade_frontalface exceeds 1Mb or is null. There is a limitation of 1Mb for compressed resources.